# Group rows in a datatable

Tags: c#, linq

I am interested in grouping some rows in a datatable after 2 columns and save the results in another datatable. I have the following code for grouping the rows:

```
var result = from t in newtable.AsEnumerable()
               group t by new { Col1= t.Field<String>("ID1"), Col2=  t.Field<String>("ID2") } into grp
                 select new
                 {
                     Col1= grp.Key.ID1,
                     Col2= grp.Key.ID2
                 };
```

How can I easily convert `result` into a datatable?

Comment: Does `result` expose the CopyToDataTable method? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just use `CopyToDatatable` with your resultant query:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from t in newtable.AsEnumerable()
group t by new { Col1 = t.Field<String>("ID1"), Col2 = t.Field<String>("ID2") } into grp
 select new
{
Col1 = grp.Key.ID1,
Col2 = grp.Key.ID2
};
DataTable boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

`CopyToDatatable` is in `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` namespace

Comment: Using the code above, I am getting the following error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#3>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You have to  change var Result to IEnumerable<DataRow> query

Comment: I've used the code you provided. Just replaced the columns and data table names.

Comment: What do you have underlined? Did you add a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions from menu and added import?. Are you getting this error at compile time or runtime?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30566/discussion-between-roxana-dinca-and-carlos-landeras)

Comment: I've a similar problem with dynamical grouping using LINQ. Can you please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694680/how-to-use-linq-for-conditional-grouping-and-filtering-on-a-datatable)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply `foreach`  loop something like that

```
foreach (var item in results)
                {
                    Datatable dt = new DataTable();
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["Col1"] = item.Col1;
                    dr["Col2"] = item.Col2;
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
```

You have to apply this type of scenario.

Hope it works.